# Modern and popular ICs for 5 V, 3 A switching regulator

Tags: power-supply, switching-regulator

I'm designing a simple power supply with the following requirements:

- Input: 120 VAC - 240 VAC
- Output: 5 V @ 3 A
- Reasonable cost & future-proof

It seems like the LM2576 switching regulator has been a long-standing solution to this problem. However, the [TI datasheet](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm2576.pdf) suggests that there are newer alternatives (e.g. LM51430, LM76003) and several variants have gone obsolete already.

Is this just advertising, or is the LM2576 becoming obsolete? If it's becoming obsolete, what are some of the more modern and popular ICs used in 5 V, 3 A switching regulators?

Answer (score 2):

The LM2576 is only a DC-DC stepdown regulator. You need a separate IC to do the line switching, which converts 120-240VAC to a lower DC voltage. This can be done with a flyback AC/DC converter ([TOP247YN](https://au.element14.com/power-integrations/top247yn/ac-dc-conv-125w-40-to-150deg-c/dp/9921290) for example). An additional stepdown switcher is not necessary, as the chip can output a voltage of your choosing (albeit considerably noisy, but as expected of a switcher). Just because a part is marked obsolete doesn't mean you can't use it, unless you are planning to mass-produce the end product.

Alternatively, you can also buy premade DIN rail PSUs that do all the AC/DC conversion for you, which is a cheaper and easier solution.

Answer (score 0):

There's really a lot of 5V, XXX A regulator IC to choose, the only problem is your input....you want to convert a power line AC to 5V DC? You need a lot of jobs and that definitely couldn't be done with a single chip. I'd recommend you to buy a 5V switching power source directly, like this one:

https://hken.rs-online.com/web/p/switching-power-supplies/7059769

There's a bunch of similar products you could buy on Amazon or your local shops.